# How often are prime powers next to factorials.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

Consider:$$7! = 7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2\cdot 1 = 5040$$
We also have:
$$71^2 = 5041$$

How often does it happen that a factorial is right next to ($\pm 1$) a prime power (exponent $>1$)? Since factorials grow so quickly we can consider how many percent of $n$ s.t. $\exists p,k:$ $$n! = p^k\pm1, \cases{n\in \mathbb Z\\k\in \{2,3,\cdots\}\ \\p \text{ prime}}$$

---

**Own work:**
So far checked $n<10$ by hand:

$$\begin{align*}5^2 &= 4!+1\\11^2&=5!+1\\71^2&=7!+1\end{align*}$$

I suppose some language with "big-int" types would be very helpful as $n!$ grows very fast.

Comment: Take a look here https://oeis.org/A088054

Comment: @RobertZ: wow there are surprisingly many sequences on there.

Comment: I know very little about number theory but I would guess powers of primes should happen more often since we have more combinations $p,k$ to choose from than if we can only choose $p$ and $k=1$.

Comment: I think you'd find a fair few because any prime that divides into n! can't be a divisor of n! but that set is so small as n! grows.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Yes I also think they could be quite common.

Comment: one good inspection of this is that n!+2 ..n!+k for some values of n and k are all composite.

Comment: for a language ( after edits) you might try [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The standard way to show that there are arbitary large prime gaps

Comment: @Peter and ( so what is new ) ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Nothing new, just a comment for those not knowing this claim and/or the proof

Comment: There are no further solutions for $n\le 10^4$, so I think you found them all. The first equation $(5^2+1=4!)$ is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63923/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-peter).

Comment: @Peter: Yes, sorry the +1 was on the wrong side. No more under $10^{4}$? Okay that is curious. I would expect quite many actually.

Comment: @mathreadler In almost any sort of search for numbers of the form $n^k$ for $k\geq 2$ (in this case, of the form $p^k$ for prime $p$, but that doesn't really change the conclusion, and where the class of numbers we're searching within is $m!-1$ (or $m!\pm 1$)), you should expect the $k=2$ cases to dominate by far, because there are _far_ fewer instances of any other type. There are $\sqrt{10^6}=1000$ squares less than or equal to $10^6$; there are no more than $\sqrt[3]{10^6}+\sqrt[4]{10^6}+\ldots=206$ higher powers (and in fact there are fewer than this, because of double-counting).

Comment: Yes no squares but any other exponents could end in 99.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of prime powers (exponent > 1) up to $x$ is roughly $\sqrt{x}/(2\log x)$ so I'd estimate the "probability" that a natural number $n$ has the property that $n!\pm 1=$prime power to be roughly $1/(\sqrt{n!}\log n!)$.  This suggests that there are only finitely many such $n$.

Comment: Does the expected value integral converge or why does it suggest so? I am also curious if you can expand the explanation a bit. I suppose the estimate comes from the prime number theorem?

Comment: Yes, the estimate comes from the prime number theorem.  Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(\sqrt{n!}\log n!)$ converges, I'd expect only finitely many solutions $n$.

Comment: Okay that reasoning sounds fair enough but I think usually people would want a more detailed answer.

Comment: @mathreadler These are heuristics, not a proof; there isn't much more detail to give here.